# How can I call function from an imported module and then when i return to the original module use the text menu correctly?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I call option `[1]` that takes me to the `createDirectory()` which once its carried out its function returns me to the `main_menu()`. I then can't call option `[1]` again, how can get it so I can call option `[1]` again?

File 1:

```
import os
from os import makedirs, path
import shutil


def main_menu():
    while True:
            # loop = 1
            # if loop == 1:
                    print("PLEASE CHOOSE AN OPTION BELOW BY ENTERING THE CORRESPONDING NUMBER: \n")

                    print("[1]: CREATE CASE FOLDER STRUCTURE")

                    print("[2]: DELETE X-WAYS CARVING FOLDER")

                    print("[3]: BACK CASE UP TO SERVER")

                    print("[4]: CLOSE PROGRAMME \n")

                    while True:
                        # choice = int(input("ENTER YOUR CHOICE HERE:"))
                            try:
                                    choice = int(input("ENTER YOUR CHOICE HERE:"))
                                    if choice == 1:
                                            # loop = 0
                                            from CreateDirectory import create_directory
                                            # main_menu()
                                            # break



                                    elif choice == 2:
                                            import RemoveFolder
                                            break

                                    elif choice == 3:
                                            caseBackup()
                                            break

                                    elif choice == 4:

                                            break

                                    else:
                                            print("INVALID CHOICE!! PLEASE ENTER A NUMBER BETWEEN 1-3")
                                            main_menu()

                            except ValueError:
                                    print("INVALID CHOICE!! PLEASE ENTER A NUMBER BETWEEN 1-3")
                                    main_menu()

if __name__ == "__main_menu__":
    main_menu()

main_menu()
```

File 2:

```
import os
from os import makedirs, path
import sys
sys.path.append('C:/Users/Matthew/Desktop/HTCU Scripts')

def createDirectory(targetPath):
    if  not path.exists(targetPath):
        makedirs(targetPath)
        print('Created folder ' + targetPath)

    else:
        print('Path ' + targetPath + ' already exists, skipping...')


# MAIN #

print('''Case Folder Initialiser
v 1.1 2015/09/14
A simple Python script for creating the folder structure required for new        cases as follows;

05 DF 1234 15
+--Acquisitions
¦  ---QQ1
¦  ---QQ2
¦  ---...
+--Case File
¦  ---X Ways
¦  +--EnCase
¦  ¦  +--Temp
¦  ¦  +--Index
¦  +--NetClean
+--Export
   ---X Ways Carving

All user inputs are not case sensitive.
''')

driveLetter = input('Enter the drive letter for your WORKING COPY disc:      ').upper()

limaReference = input('Enter the Lima reference number, such as 05 DF 12345 15: ').upper()

rootPath = driveLetter + ':/' + limaReference + '/'

print('You will now enter your exhibit references, such as QQ1. Press enter   at an empty prompt to stop adding further exhibits.')

exhibits = []
while True:
    exhibit = input('Enter exhibit reference: ').upper()
    if not exhibit:
        print('You have finished adding exhibits and the folders will now be created.')
        break

    exhibits.append(exhibit)

for exhibit in exhibits:
    targetPath = rootPath + '/Acquisitions/' + exhibit + '/'
    createDirectory(targetPath)

targetPath = rootPath + 'Case File/X Ways/'
createDirectory(targetPath)

targetPath = rootPath + 'Case File/EnCase/Temp/'
createDirectory(targetPath)

targetPath = rootPath + 'Case File/EnCase/Index/'
createDirectory(targetPath)

targetPath = rootPath + 'Case File/NetClean/'
createDirectory(targetPath)

targetPath = rootPath + 'Export/X Ways Carving/'
createDirectory(targetPath)

print('All folders created, script has terminated.\n')


if __name__ == "__createDirectory__":
    createDirectory(targetPath)

from TestMain import main_menu
```

Comment: You should definitely not be modifying sys.path in modules you import.

Comment: How would I go about calling file 2 from file 1 if didn't use this?

Comment: I can't even begin to answer that. This really isn't how you use imports.

Comment: I have changed it now, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a fundamental understanding of how to construct and use modules. Modules are not "called", they are "imported" in order to access functions within that module. Your original post improperly used the import statement, when it should only be used once and by convention at the top of your module.

Beware of circular references, by the way, because you don't want to have Module A import Module B which then references back to Module A. That should never be necessary.

So your main module (named `main.py` in my example) might look like this:

```
from myDirUtils import create_folder_structure, remove_folder, case_backup

def main_menu():
    finished = False
    while not finished:
        print("PLEASE CHOOSE AN OPTION BELOW BY ENTERING THE CORRESPONDING NUMBER: \n")
        print("[1]: CREATE CASE FOLDER STRUCTURE")
        print("[2]: DELETE X-WAYS CARVING FOLDER")
        print("[3]: BACK CASE UP TO SERVER")
        print("[4]: CLOSE PROGRAMME \n")
        try:
            choice = int(input("ENTER YOUR CHOICE HERE:"))
            if choice == 1:
                create_folder_structure()
            elif choice == 2:
                remove_folder()
            elif choice == 3:
                case_backup()
            elif choice == 4:
                finished = True
            else:
                print("INVALID CHOICE!! PLEASE ENTER A NUMBER BETWEEN 1-3")
        except ValueError:
            print("INVALID CHOICE!! PLEASE ENTER A NUMBER BETWEEN 1-3")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # execute only if run as a script
    main_menu()
```

With your second module (named `myDirUtils.py` and placed in the same directory as `main.py') defined like this:

```py
from os import makedirs, path

def create_folder_structure():
    print('--- all your instructions ---')
    driveLetter = 'D'
    limaReference = 'lima'
    rootPath = driveLetter + ':/' + limaReference + '/'
    # build exhibits here
    targetPath = rootPath + 'CaseFile/XWays/'
    _create_directory(targetPath)
    targetPath = rootPath + 'CaseFile/Encase/Temp'
    _create_directory(targetPath)

def remove_folder():
    print("in remove_folder...")

def case_backup():
    print("in case_backup...")

def _create_directory(targetPath):
    print("in create_directory...")
    if not path.exists(targetPath):
        print('now we have to create the folder')
        # makedirs(targetPath)
    else:
        print('Path ' + targetPath + ' already exists, skipping...')
```

Comment: Thanks for this PeterT it good advice and wasn't to hard to implement.